# Why do I get an error when I log out with Firebase Auth?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, logout

this is my logout code:

```
  onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                await widget.checkLogin();
              },
```

This is my CheckLogin function:

```
  checkLogin() async {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      login = true;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      login = false;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

The error it gives me after logging out is the following:

```
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

With various attempts I realized that the problem lies in these lines of code, but I don't know how to fix ...

```
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("temp");
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      ref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
        final snapshot = event.snapshot.value;
        if (snapshot != null) {
          Object? temp = snapshot;

          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {});
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: I would assume that you are not allowed to read from the database when you are logged out: in `FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("temp");`

Comment: exactly, to read or write to the database the user must be authenticated…

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your Firebase Console And Update your rules like this

Select Database From Side Menu --> Select Rule From tabs above --> Update your rule like this

```
  {
        "rules": {    
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: for what i need the rules must in the database dictate that the user must be authenticated to read or write

Comment: if you are developing the app you can try changing those values to fix your issue if this don't fix your issue please add comment

Comment: yours is a temporary solution, I would need a definitive solution as they are in pre-launch